# Type is not assignable to Type which implements it

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ngrx

After the latest update from vs studio code I am getting an error in one of my ngrx reducers.

> Argument of type 'Action' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'SwitchDeviceAction'.
>   Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"SWITCH_DEVICE_ACTION"'.

**reducer**

```
export function uiStateReducer(state: UiState = INITIAL_UI_STATE, action: Action): UiState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SWITCH_DEVICE_ACTION:
      return handleSwicthDeviceAction(state, action); // error is on this action
    // ...
  }
}

export function handleSwicthDeviceAction(state: UiState, action: SwitchDeviceAction): UiState {
  const newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
  newState.device = action.payload;
  return newState;
}
```

but this shouldn't throw a type error since `SwitchDeviceAction` implements `Action`.

```
export const SWITCH_DEVICE_ACTION = 'SWITCH_DEVICE_ACTION';
export class SwitchDeviceAction implements Action {
    readonly type = SWITCH_DEVICE_ACTION;
    constructor(public payload?: string) { }
}
```

This is the case for all Actions passed through my reducers and the errors only appeared after the latest vs studio code update. My program seems to work fine. **Am I breaking from convention in some way that merits this warning or is this as oversight from vs studio code?**

Comment: Could be related to this bug of the string literal bug in typescript 2.1+  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13580

Comment: I had the same issue but once i reloaded after an extension update, I got a TSC warning and the issue went away